# localhost in a DNS zone

Tags: domain-name-system, localhost

Our ISP also hosts our external DNS. By default they include an entry for localhost.

For example:
localhost.example.com. 86400 IN A 127.0.0.1

When I've asked them to remove it they give me a hard time and say that it's just the way Bind works.

I've tried to do some research on why I might want to have that included but I couldn't find much. I did find at least one place that thought it be a possible XSS attack vector. It does appear to be fairly common so I did lookups on the top 20 website domains from alexa and most don't have such an entry but a couple do. A few others have an entry but instead of pointing to 127.0.0.1 they point to another a world route-able IP address.

So anyway, why would I want to have locahost in the zone for my domain? Are their any issues with not having it? Is there any kind of best practice concerning this? Is it indeed a default Bind thing that I'm not aware of?

Thanks

Comment: Good question. I never heard of that before.

Comment: I have even a "loopback" in my ISPs zone file. WTF?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`localhost.example.com` is sometimes included on internal DNS servers to prevent "localhost" requests leaking out to the internet (for the case where John Smith types `http://localhost/` in his browser & for whatever reason his resolver doesn't look in the hosts file, appends his search path (`example.com`) & starts asking name servers what that resolves to).

You don't have to have a localhost entry (and if your ISP thinks that's "the way BIND works" they're either misguided or idiots: BIND serves what's in the zone file, and if they remove the `localhost` line it will stop serving that record).  As a free example, `localhost.google.com` doesn't resolve, and I bet the NS for that domain is running BIND.

The XSS vector is something I'd never thought of, but it is something of concern: having a `localhost` entry in your public DNS means any hacked machine could be "in your domain" (by running a webserver on 127.0.0.1) and potentially do all sorts of nasty things.  Probably a good enough reason to get rid of the entry.

Comment: Personally I'd think that `localhost.some.test` is just another victim of **not** getting proper dot ending. The reasoning behind having `localhost.` (note the dot!) is clear, but dots are often forgotten in DNS zones. Then it sprung to have its own mysterious life.

Comment: See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1537 Common DNS Data File Configuration Errors which suggest that the localhost entry is correct.

Comment: No, rfc1537 does not specifiy that. It specifies that recursors need to have a localhost. zone and a zone for the reverse. Nowhere does it say your zones need a localhost entry.

Comment: @BillThor [The comments on this other answer](http://serverfault.com/a/120784/32986) are relevant to RFC 1537 and its successor (RFC 1912) - As Habbie mentioned the *zone* `localhost.` is something we're supposed to have, but the practice of having a `localhost` *record* in each zone we serve has fallen out of favor. (This question actually lead me down that RFC rabbit hole 5 years ago, maybe I'll update my answer with the new RFC & thoughts from that comment thread later :))

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your internal name resolution is handling name resolution properly, any DNS request for localhost should never go to your external DNS provider, and so this shouldn't be a problem at all.

One reason *why* someone would do this, that I can think of off the top of my head, is if someone once used a web authoring tool that screwed up with a load of absolute references to http://localhost, but that assumes that your ISP was also hosting on their DNS boxes and is a long shot.

However, [RFC 1537](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1537) *does* specify:

> There has been extensive discussion
> about whether or not to append the
> local domain to it. The conclusion was
> that "localhost." would be the best
> solution; reasons given were:
>
> - "localhost" itself is used and expected to work on some systems.
> - translating 127.0.0.1 into "localhost.my_domain" can cause some
>   software to connect to itself using the loopback interface when
>   it didn't want to.
>
> Note that all domains that contain
> hosts should have a "localhost" A
> record in them.

So strictly speaking it appears as though your ISP is correct to include localhost, but incorrect to use the fully-qualified name.

Comment: Looks like RFC-1537 was obsoleted by RFC-1912 which deletes the `Note that ...` language (I'd guess in response to the potential XSS issues which we would have started to be aware of in 1996 :)  1537 Explains why it's in the BIND templates though.

Comment: do you mean there should be an entry like this in the zone for example.com:

localhost. 86400 IN A 127.0.0.1 ; note the period

Comment: 4.1 of 1912 is actually quite explicit on it: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt

Comment: 5 years on but worth clarifying: 4.1 of RFC 1912 is explicit that the `localhost` ***zone*** should exist on the server (so if it gets a request just plain "localhost" it doesn't pass it up the chain to the next server), that's a far cry from including `localhost` in say `example.com`'s zone (creating `localhost.example.com`), which it is equally explicit in saying you should *not* do because of possible unintended side effects. The expectation is for "localhost" to be a special, magical, fully-qualified domain in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the point would be...By default, the external address would be over-ridden by the hosts file, which nearly always maps localhost to 127.0.0.1.

A default BIND zone file does include a localhost zone, though. Never really thought about it.

Comment: This is not the localhost zone (unless its a mis-configuration of that zone). It's also not the fqdn 'localhost.' and would not generally be over-ridden by the local hosts file.