# Practical effects of setting dev.example.com to 127.0.0.1

Tags: domain-name-system, security, development

The idea is to point a DNS entry to 127.0.0.1, so that it's possible to test "inline installation" of browser extensions.

Here's an example service that does this:  http://readme.localtest.me/

I'm considering doing this for my own DNS entries.

```
app.example.com        -> production server IP
app-stage.example.com  -> stage servier IP
app-dev.example.com    -> 127.0.0.1
```

Then I can put my app locally to respond to app-dev.example.com and test.

I'm following up on [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36491/is-it-safe-to-have-a-dns-record-pointing-to-127-0-0-1) from a practical standpoint.  The answers generally said there was little security risk for pointing app-dev.example.com to 127.0.0.1.

XSS is a [concern in the DNS configs](https://serverfault.com/questions/120769/localhost-in-a-dns-zone), but that seems different.

Are you aware of a practical issues?

Obviously, each person resolving the DN would need the app installed and working on their machine.

Seems fine, but then ?

Thanks!

Comment: Downvote reason?

Comment: I've been doing this for awhile and it's been fine.  It seems like a common practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just be sure the DNS you're using is yours, under your control.

But as for your question considering you're thinking of other developers i suppose this is your case already.

You can have issues if your app calls other services under that same domain that point to 127.0.0.1, in this case you will have trouble connecting to those endpoints, but if your application is self contained i dont see none.